# How do I fetch a value in a ManyToOne relationship mapping via @Query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to fetch distinct values of multiple columns from a table SubContactModel where I would search using the a value, which in this case is the email.

While I am able to obtain distinct values, what I am trying to obtain now is to fetch the values inside a
field that is mapped with @ManyToOne. As of now, I can only obtain the Foreign Key (FK) but I would like to fetch another value from the relationship. For example, I would like to obtain the value countryphonecode from the CountryPhoneCodeModel. I have included my repository layer to show how am I obtaining the distinct values right now.

SubContactModel:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class SubContactModel implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "SUBCONTACTID", updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long subcontactID;
    
    @ManyToOne() 
    @JoinColumn(name="PRSNTITLEID", nullable=true, updatable=true)
    private PersonTitleModel personTitleID;  // Person Title
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryPhonecode", nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private CountryPhoneCodeModel countryPhoneCodeModel; // Country Code 

    
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String name;

    
    @Column(name = "designation", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "telnumber", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String telnumber;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String email;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="PERSONID", nullable=true, updatable=true)
    private PersonModel personID;
    
}
```

CountryPhoneCodeModel:

```
public class CountryPhoneCodeModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="CPHONECODEID",updatable = false,unique = true,nullable = false )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long countryPhoneCodeID;
    
    @Column(name="CPHONECODE",updatable=true,nullable=false,length=50)
    private String countryPhoneCode;
    
    @Column(name="COUNTRYNAME",updatable=true,nullable=false,length=50)
    private String countryName;
    
    @Column(name="DIALCODE",updatable=true,nullable=false,length=50)
    private String dialCode;
}
```

Repository layer :

```
@Repository
public interface SubContactRepo extends JpaRepository<SubContactModel, Long> {
     
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT u.designation,u.name,u.telnumber,u.countryphonecode,u.prsntitleid FROM subcontactmodel u WHERE u.email = :email", nativeQuery = true)
    List <Object> findDistinctResult (String email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this:

I removed nativeQuery = true and changed the fields names in the @Query to match the name in my entity instead of the table column names in the database.

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT u.designation,u.name,u.telnumber, u.countryPhoneCodeModel.countryPhoneCode ,u.personTitleID.personTitleName FROM SubContactModel u WHERE u.email= :email")
List <Object> findDistinctResult (String email);
```

Now it works the way I want it!